# Android get all Images in HTTP responses

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, picasso

I have a URL that is not with any image suffix (i.e. .jpg), but a `.com`.
but slide through images, and images are being returned on HTTP responses.
I'm familiar with Glide, but how do I download an image at a time?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Parse the URL response, find the image URLs you need, then feed those to Glide.

Comment: Agreed, use something like jsoup to parse the HTML, and extract the images matching your pattern.

Comment: Thanks @dominicoder , I was afraid that this is the only options. Just sounds "script-kid" to me

Comment: Well it sounds like you're scraping a site - i.e. "script kid" - so, yeah. Ideally you would have an API to work with that returned structured data.